# Login loop after changing username

Tags: 14.04, login, username

I'm using 14.04. Basically I changed my machines name (via root) from x@x to y@y. Problem is after doing this I get stuck in a login loop - I enter my details screen goes black and returns me to the login page. If I change my details back to x@x from y@y I can login again though I need it to be x@x. Any ideas how I can fix this? Many thanks.

Comment: Try `sudo rm .Xauthority` from tty1

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>. In the TTY enter your loginname and password then do the following:

```
sudo mv -v /home/old-username /home/new-username
sudo chown -Rv new-username:new-usergroup /home/new-username
rm -fv ~/.Xauthority
exit
```

Now press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd> to go back to the GUI and login normaly.

Comment: It worked! but after mod my username when I try log in the old user appears